# calculating 2 sides of a triangle with a known angle of 45 degress ending at 86.33 width

Tags: geometry

I have a trailer hitch with an angle of $45^\text{o}$. I am looking to figure out the length of the $2$ legs reaching out at that angle until it reaches an width of $86.33$ inches.  The $2$ lengths must remain equal to keep the trailer towing straight.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have thoughts and have tried things you can share? Regards

Answer (score 2):

The two sides will each have length
$$\frac{86.33}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin 22.5^\circ}.$$
My calculator gives, approximately, $112.79558$.

**Remark:** Draw the isosceles triangle $ABC$ with two equal sides $AB$ and $AC$, and angle of $45^\circ$ at $A$. We are told that $BC=86.33$.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Look at $\triangle AMB$. The angle $MAB$ is $22.5^\circ$. It follows that
$$\frac{BM}{AB}=\sin(22.5^\circ).$$
Use the fact that $BM=\frac{86.33}{2}$ to solve for $AB$.

There are other ways to find the length. For example, let $x$ be the length of one of the desired sides. By the Cosine Law, we have
$$(86.33)^2=2x^2-2\cos(45^\circ)x^2.$$
But $\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and therefore
$$x=\frac{86.33}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}.$$